# How to solve ESLint Error with unexpected Token?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

I'm using a Vue/TS application to read JSON and to comapre them. But I have a linter error.

Here is the error :

> 319:33  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?

The line 319:33 is the line where I check for the length of the files in this code below :

```
handleFileInput(e:Event) {
      const target:HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>e.target
      const id:string = target?.id
      console.log(id)
      const files:FileList|null = target.files
      if (files && files?.length > 0) {
        const file = files[0]
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = () => {
          const res = JSON.parse(<string>reader.result)
          if (id === "fileBr") {
            this.br.json = res
            this.br.name = file.name
          } else if (id === 'fileC') {
            this.c.json = res
            this.c.name = file.name
          }
        }
        reader.readAsText(file)
      }
    },
```

Do someone have any idea if there is a code problem or a bad configuration of es-lint ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this `files && files.length > 0`

Comment: Yes I already tried it.

Answer (score 1):

`<string>` is only valid syntax in tsx files. You should use `as string` or a typecheck insted. The same goes for the `<HTMLInputElement>`.

```js
const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;

...

const res = JSON.parse(reader.result as string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found !

I should use : reader.result as string instead of reader.result

That's why I have unexpected tokens

Comment: Ok, that was my original answer, but I deleted it when I read that the error occurred in the line where you check the length of `files`